# Rails 7, ActiveMailer smtp is not setting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I have this in config/development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'apikey',
    :password => '****', 
    :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

and
If run this on runtime,

```
(byebug) Rails.configuration.action_mailer.smtp_settings
{:open_timeout=>5, :read_timeout=>5}
(byebug)
```

It doesn't seem to take full settings. I suspect that this will end up not sending emails with error

*** Errno::ECONNREFUSED Exception: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You seem to be missing `:enable_starttls_auto => true` in the `smtp_settings` - see https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails

Comment: No. I added it. and got same result.

Answer (score 6):

Ok I figured out.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails
was wrong.

has to be this format.

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => 'apikey',
    :password => '***',
    :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Not  ***ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings***

Comment: Rails 7.0.1 has this issue. They have explained it here. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44161